# OracleCacheDependency on mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

I'm implementing an asp.net mvc3 site with oracle server. And I'm struggling with Oracle Cache Provider for .NET.

I've searched pretty much on oracle document and msdn. But I couldn't find any useful example to use for implementation with OracleCacheDependency.

I wrote the codes below but It doesn't work. According to my assumption 'actual' should be null or string.Empty because database is updated after inserted to cache. But the cachedependency and cache haven't changed any thing.

```
public CacheDependency GetOracleCacheDependency(string query)
{
    string connStr = DatabaseConfig.ConnectionStringForViewer;
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn)
    return new OracleCacheDependency(cmd);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void GetCacheDependencyTest()
{
    string selectQuery = @"SELECT * FROM TABLE_USER";
    string updateQuery = @"UPDATE TABLE_USER SET EMAILADDRESS='test1@test.com' WHERE USR_USERID='00001'";
    string cacheKey = "TESTKEY";
    string cacheValue = "TESTVALUE";
    CacheDependency dependency = GetOracleCacheDependency(selectQuery);
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null), new HttpResponse(null));

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, cacheValue, dependency);

    DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
    dbManager.ExecuteNonQuery(updateQuery, values);

    string expected = null;
    string actual = cache[cacheKey] as string;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Did I miss something like configuration on web.config or machine.config to make cache look to database? I just installed Oracle Provider, add references to the project and coded.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. What I was missing is executing the oracle command like below.

```
public CacheDependency GetOracleCacheDependency(string query)
{
    string connStr = DatabaseConfig.ConnectionStringForViewer;
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn)
    OracleCacheDependency dependency = new OracleCacheDependency(cmd);

    //This registers dependency to database.
    cmd.ExcuteReader();

    return dependency;
}
```

Now it works fine for me.